# Weird VBA (Bug?)- Copy Paste Loop Crashes, unless Messagebox is added

Tags: vba, loops, crash

I have got a weird problem with VBA. I have programmed a sub that is supposed to create a Word report. I basically have e.g. 10 variablles, a word template document with template charts, and for each variable three CSV files with data. I loop over all variables, and for each variable I create page, access the chartdata workbook, and copy the external CSV data into the chartdata workbook.

```
Sub createRep()

  'open Word-template

  for page=1 to 10

    'Open external csv
    'Open chartdata workbook
    'Copy external data into chartdata workbook
    'Close external csv files and chartdata workbook

  Next page

End Sub
```

It will work in the beginning, but at a certain page I will get an error because the pasting does not work. I cannot copy anything into the chartdata workbook manually either, it seems like it crashed and that is why the pasting failed. However, the following code will work:

```
Sub createRep()

  'open Word-template

  for page=1 to 10

    MsgBox page

    'Open external csv
    'Open chartdata workbook
    'Copy external data into chartdata workbook
    'Close external csv files and chartdata workbook

  Next page

End Sub
```

That is the message box fixes it somehow. But why?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to your code running ahead of Word opening. While the document tries to load, you are already accessing it before the application is ready.
Do fixes to this you could try are just adding `DoEvents` or if this is not enough, using your reference to the WordApplication do:

```
While WordApplication.Busy = True
      DoEvents
Wend
```

Hope this helps
-JDB